# How can i share the ssh private key with multiple system users using the ssh agent?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent, bastion-host

I have a linux bastion server that acts as a gateway for administrators to access multiple servers via SSH.

I would like to give these system users ssh access to the servers through the gateway but prefer not share the private-key(s). Is there a way to give users access to the same ssh-agent but without sharing the private key?

Comment: This is a programming forum! Server administration is OT here!

Comment: @Klaus Ah right, time to migrate my question to server fault.